# Removing percentage from numbers in a list

Tags: python

I have a list containing the numbers in the picture below:

[image]

I need to find a way to remove 30 percent off of every item in it and store them in a new list.

any help on getting this done?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was thinking of making a loop that will iterate each element in the list, multiply it by 0.3 and then subtract it by the answer I got after multiplying by 0.3. I have no idea where to go from here...

Comment: What part of the problem do you have trouble with? Iterating over a list? Constructing a new list? Doing both with a comprehension? Computing a value that's 30% less than another? (your suggestion in the comments is fine as a starting point - please share your code; as a hint `x - (x * .3)` is the same as `x * (1 - .3)` or `x * .7`)

Comment: You can even use list comprehensions.  new_li = [ i * 0.7 for i in old_list]

Answer (score 1):

Consider `x` as our test data:

```py
x = [120,
     100,
     90,
     0]
```

---

Solving:

Via iteration and appendage:

```py
y = []

for number in x:
    # *0.7 is -30% | Which is equivalent to x-(x*0.3)
    y.append(x*0.7)
```

Via list comprehension

```py
y = [i*0.7 for i in x]
```

---

Outputs:

```
[84.0, 70.0, 62.99999999999999, 0.0]
```

Comment: That looks close to what I came up with! Turns out my issue was that I didn't know where to put the 0.7 which really confused me. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @sounaz, no worries man! Don't forget to show your own code with your next question too

Answer (score 0):

Here's Logic:-

1. Iterate through list and store as float value and make a empty list above loop
2. make another variable to get 30% of the stored value
3. Subtract it
4. use append() to insert the value in list(new)

Answer (score 0):

```
items = [100, 200, 300]
iterator = map(lambda item: item-item*0.3 , items)
print(list(iterator))
```

this is equivalent to this code:

```
def remove_thirty_percent(item):   
return item-item*0.3

items = [100, 200, 300]
iterator = map(remove_thirty_percent , items)
print(list(iterator))
```

to learn more about Python map() function: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/

Answer (score 0):

Two methods to solve it
1.

```
def percent(mylist):
    newlist = []
    for each in mylist:
        each = each - (each * 0.3)
        newlist.append(each)
    return newlist

lst = [130.00,153.00,221.00,117.00,55.00,200.00]

print(percent(lst))

#Output:[91.0, 107.1, 154.7, 81.9, 38.5, 140.0]
```

2. 

```
def percent2(mylist):
    return [x-(x*0.3) for x in mylist]

lst = [130.00,153.00,221.00,117.00,55.00,200.00]

print(percent2(lst))

#output: [91.0, 107.1, 154.7, 81.9, 38.5, 140.0]
```